# Python C Extension with Numpy

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm trying to create a C Extension for Python with Numpy and have some problems reading the data from Numpy in my C code.

If I create a simple array like this in Python I'm able to read the values in the C code:

Python:

```
from numpy import *
myarray = zeros([5, 20], dtype=uint32)
```

C:

```
value = (unsigned long*)PyArray_GETPTR2(myarray,0,0);
```

The problem is when I try to read the value from the following Numpy Array:

Python:

```
from numpy import *
myarray = zeros([5], dtype=[('f1', 'S16'), ('f2', 'S16'), ('f3', uint64), ('f4', uint32)] )
```

C:

```
value = (void*)PyArray_GETPTR1(myarray,0);
```

What kind og data type is the value in this case?

Comment: What errors do you get? Are they at compile or run time?

Comment: I don't really get an error. I just don't know howto read the S16, S16, uint64 and uint32 from value.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy structured data types are by default equivalent to C packed structs. They can, however, also be more complicated.

To access the fields, check e.g. `myarray.dtype.fields['f3']`, which in your case is `(dtype('uint64'), 32)`. You should be able to access the corresponding data via `(npy_uint64*)(((char*)value) + 32)`.